# Stopping data from reloading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started writing an application with AngularJS and I have a couple questions about data persistence across routes.  [Here a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l4nSNt1MENCeAxBbz7lI?p=info) of a simple list application that demonstrates my question.  Right now, each time a controller is loaded an HTTP request is being made.  I only want a single HTTP request to be sent when the app is loaded and then be able to use that data in both of my views.

Question 1: When I click on a list item, how can I use the data that was loaded in ListCtrl rather than issuing another request to pull that same data(but for a single item)?

Question 2: If I've click on an item and then click the back button, how can I make it so that ListCtrl doesn't re-issue a request to get all the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory).  You can use it to construct cache objects to store your data.

Also, this guy has a pretty good post on using it for what you are looking for, so I won't reinvent the wheel here.

http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/caching-json-arrays-using-cachefactory-in-angularjs-1-2-x/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @e-sushi I normally do add code if necessary, but I thought by providing the factory name he was looking for, the link to the documentation and then another link as reference was including all the essentials.

Comment: I agree with @kevindeleon. Plus, he did include the essential parts. The first link looks broken at the end, though.

Comment: OK, now it looks better. Thanks, Community, whoever you are, you did more with 1 rep than many people do with thousands!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 : You can save the data on `$rootScope` so the data accessible by all `$scope`.

Answer 2 : You can `cache` your ajax so AngularJS will only request the data at first service call, and use it for the rest service call.